# Band calculations using satellite images captured on different dates

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, image, satellite, band

I want to do some band calculations using bands taken from multi spectral (MS)  satellite images and bands from a short-wave infrared (SWIR) image. I have one SWIR image covering the whole area of interest, one MS image covering the eastern half of the AOI and one MS image covering the western half. The problem is that the 2 MS images were captured on different dates, and so the band values in each image are different, even for the same pixel (there is a small region of overlap between the 2 MS images). This of course affects the results of the band calculations, causing the western half and Eastern half of the final output image to look quite different from each other.
Is there any technique that can be used to normalize the values in the 2 MS images to reduce the difference between them or do I just have to accept that as the raw band values are different, this will feed through to the final output?

Comment: Kindly mention the software you are using.

Comment: I can use QGIS or python/rasterio to do image preprocessing and the band calculations

Comment: This is the general rationale behind radiometric correction (conversion to reflectance) and the creation of normalized indices using band to band ratios such as NDVI. Even if the images were captured on the same day, the illumination conditions are dynamic and need to be accounted for.

Comment: @Kartograaf - thanks, I think that's put me on the right track... now looking at converting WV3-3 DN to reflectance values...

Answer (score 0):

if they are the satellite images, can you search if there are new images in the required dates. Or you could also share about which satellite data you are using, it would be more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately,  obtaining images from the same dates is not possible, the MS images I have are the only images available for this area of interest. They are worldview-3 images.